# Review queue tests are not always valid; there should be an option to appeal a test

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After failing a review queue test there should be a button to appeal the test, which later can be reviewed by other people, to remove temporary bans.

Some questions are invalid, but upvoted because they are important information to the community, but they should not be allow to be integrated as a test.

[image]

This question is very broad and misleading, and the majority of the information to understand the question is third party and not part of our site.